# Method not calling on click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, tailwind-css

I was trying to make a slider with **Vue JS**
 I have somehow managed to add background and bottom bullets working. But slide anchors (prev and next) function is not firing @click.
**HTML of only anchors**. [Link to complete html](https://chaggy-vuetodo.web.app/sliders)

```
        <div class="left-anchor w-8 h-8 text-white" @click="sliderCount(-1)">
          <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M11 19l-7-7 7-7m8 14l-7-7 7-7" />
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="right-anchor w-8 h-8 text-white" @click="sliderCount(1)" >
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M13 5l7 7-7 7M5 5l7 7-7 7" />
          </svg>
        </div>
```

**Script**

```
export default {
data:function(){
    return{
        interval:"",
        currentSlide:0,
        images:['alexandr.jpg','pixabay.jpg','tim-mossholder.jpg'],
        image:''
    }
},
methods:{
  sliderCount:function(count){
      this.currentSlide = (this.currentSlide >= 2) ? 0 : this.currentSlide + count
  },
  setCurrentSlide:function(count) {
      this.currentSlide = count - 1
  }
},
mounted(){
},
beforeMount(){
    this.interval = ''
}
}
```

**Why isn't this @click function working?**

Comment: did you log something inside the method to check if it's called?

Comment: Yeah! Tried that. the function sliderCount(1) if called in mounted is logging. But when i click anchors its not logging. Anchors === "Prev and Next Buttons"

Comment: try out the modifiers `stop`, `selft` like `@click.stop`

Comment: Tried. Even restarted npm run serve. Still not working.

Comment: could you reproduce the issue in https://play.tailwindcss.com/ in order to debug, add vue via CDN and use online pictures

Comment: Apologies, I have never used tailwindplay.
I tried this in tailwind play but nothing is happening. https://play.tailwindcss.com/jjQmsk0Wcl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw your code and i found that the issue was not in **Vue JS**. But it was just a basic CSS issue of z-index. Just use this code in your styles tag

```
.anchors{
z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@FakeAccount is correct but since you're using tailwind should be done by adding `z-10` class without defining extra style rules :

```
 <div class="anchors z-10 ...">
```